# Include document in joomla with PHP

Tags: php, joomla, include

I'm very fresh to PHP world.

Trying to do as I think very simple thing(?)- include external file in Joomla template.

```
<?php include_once('templates/' echo $this->template  '/includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

But unfortunately it is not working.

can someone please tell me how correct string should look like?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string should look like this:

```
<?php include_once('templates/'.$this->template.'/includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

The manual on strings in PHP can be found here: [String](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)